# SQLite funções nativas X SugarRecord

Tags: android, sqlite

Quais a vantagens e desvantagem no uso do `SugarRecord` quando comparado com as funções nativas  `SQLite`,

Exemplo na criação de uma tabela com o SQLite [Funções Nativas](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

```
DatabaseHelper.java
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Logcat tag
    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_TODO = "todos";
    private static final String TABLE_TAG = "tags";
    private static final String TABLE_TODO_TAG = "todo_tags";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    // NOTES Table - column nmaes
    private static final String KEY_TODO = "todo";
    private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";

    // TAGS Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_TAG_NAME = "tag_name";

    // NOTE_TAGS Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_TODO_ID = "todo_id";
    private static final String KEY_TAG_ID = "tag_id";

    // Table Create Statements
    // Todo table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TODO + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TODO
            + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER," + KEY_CREATED_AT
            + " DATETIME" + ")";

    // Tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TAG = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TAG
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TAG_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    // todo_tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TODO_TAG = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TODO_TAG + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_TODO_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TAG_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TAG);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TODO_TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TAG);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO_TAG);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

E com o Sugar [SugarRecord](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

```
public class Book extends SugarRecord<Book> {
  String title;
  String edition;

  public Book(){
  }

  public Book(String title, String edition){
    this.title = title;
    this.edition = edition;
  }
}
```

Comment: Esse é um tipo de pergunta cuja resposta é subjetiva. De qualquer forma, as **vantagens** você pode entrar no próprio site do SugarRecord e o **desvantagens** é simplesmente ficar dependente de uma lib de terceiros quando você poderia fazer você mesmo esse serviço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desenvolver aplicações com Sugar ORM pode ser útil para aqueles que precisem persistir informações em banco de dados local e desejem usufruir do modelo ORM, não necessitando utilizar SQL para criação e manuseio de tabelas.

Sugar ORM é uma biblioteca para persistência em banco de dados que disponibiliza uma maneira simples e consistente de integrar os modelos da aplicação em um banco de dados SQLite. A principal vantagem do Sugar ORM é a sua simplicidade mas que permite a realização de tarefas um pouco mais complexas como por exemplo a utilização de relacionamentos um-para-muitos.

Podemos ver essa "simplicidade" no **[CRUD do Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)**:

**Salvar**:

```
Book book = new Book("Title here", "2nd edition")
book.save();
```

**Carregar**:

```
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
```

**Atualizar**:

```
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
book.title = "updated title here"; // modify the values
book.edition = "3rd edition";
book.save(); // updates the previous entry with new values.
```

**Deletar**:

```
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
book.delete();
```

**Operações em massa**:

```
List<Book> books = Book.listAll(Book.class);

Book.deleteAll(Book.class);
```

Já no **[SQLlite](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)**:

**Criação**:

```
/*
 * Creating a todo
 */
public long createToDo(Todo todo, long[] tag_ids) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TODO, todo.getNote());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, todo.getStatus());
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    // insert row
    long todo_id = db.insert(TABLE_TODO, null, values);

    // assigning tags to todo
    for (long tag_id : tag_ids) {
        createTodoTag(todo_id, tag_id);
    }

    return todo_id;
}
```

**Busca**:

Busca do tipo `SELECT * FROM todos WHERE id = 1;`

```
/*
 * get single todo
 */
public Todo getTodo(long todo_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + todo_id;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    Todo td = new Todo();
    td.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
    td.setNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TODO))));
    td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));

    return td;
}
```

Busca do tipo `SELECT * FROM todos;`

```
/*
 * getting all todos
 * */
public List<Todo> getAllToDos() {
    List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TODO;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Todo td = new Todo();
            td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
            td.setNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TODO))));
            td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));

            // adding to todo list
            todos.add(td);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return todos;
}
```

**Atualização**:

```
/*
 * Updating a todo
 */
public int updateToDo(Todo todo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TODO, todo.getNote());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, todo.getStatus());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_TODO, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(todo.getId()) });
}
```

**Deletar**:

```
/*
 * Deleting a todo
 */
public void deleteToDo(long tado_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TODO, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
}
```

A desvantagem é que ainda está em desenvolvimento e podem ser encontrados bugs. Segundo esse [site](http://www.christophlorenz.de/blog/selecting-an-orm-for-android/): "Se você tem um banco de dados mais complexo com mais do que apenas os campos de texto e números inteiros, ou se você tem que implementar uma migração de banco de dados, o que não pode ser feito por instruções SQL simples, você está perdido, infelizmente. Qualquer coisa além de acesso a objetos de banco de dados simples resultará em escrever código manual com instruções SQL limitados."